# How can a ReadOnly SQL Server user see how a view was created?

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a data analyst that has a read only user to our ERP databases in Microsoft SQL Server 2019. He wants to see how some views are built but for some reason that is not available to him.

For example he has no design option (which is correct) but he also can't do a `Script View as -> Create To` to see how it's defined.

Is there anyway to give them access to see how the views are created (joins, etc) but not modify them?

Comment: Your user needs to be granted VIEW DEFINITION permission. See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1593/granting-view-definition-permission-to-a-user-or-role-in-sql-server/.

Comment: Be careful with this if your views, stored procedures, functions, triggers, etc. contain any sensitive information (such as embedded passwords as a worst case).

Comment: If they can SELECT from the view but not view its definition, it's likely that there is an active DENY, which overrides the GRANT.

Comment: Thank-you [T-N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12637193/t-n) , that worked exactly as expected.  I granted the VIEW DEFINITION permission to only his user and only on the one ERP table and he can now "Design" on a view but can't save it.  If you'd like to repost as a answer I will mark it as such.